# Matrix/Vector equation involving the norm of the vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Let $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$, and $W\in\mathbb R^n$. Consider
$$\alpha V+\beta \frac{V}{\lVert V\rVert}=W$$
where $\lVert \cdot\rVert$ is the regular Euclidean norm. Is there a closed form  solution for unknown $V\in\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Note that $W$ and $V$ are parallel, so reduce to an equation in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That should do the trick. Works nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @user10354138, comment $V$ and $W$ are parallel, hence there exists a
constant $k$ such that $V=kW$. Hence
$$
\alpha kW+\beta \frac{kW}{\lVert kW\rVert}=W
\;\Leftrightarrow\;
\alpha kW+\beta \;\text{sign}(k)\frac{W}{\lVert W\rVert}=W,
$$
and therefore the problem is reduced to $\mathbb R$
$$
\alpha k+\beta \;\text{sign}(k)\frac{1}{\lVert W\rVert}=1,
$$
hence
$$
k = -\text{sign}(k)\frac{\beta}{\alpha\lVert W\rVert}\;.
$$